# Getting second digit in a string using Javascript + Regex?

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm wondering how I can get the second digit of a string where we don't know the number of digits the second number will be and without using splice or substring.

**Ex.** `Channel.0.This.13`

**Should Return**: `13`

I've seen a few similar questions but they

1. typically know the number of digits the second number will be or
2. use splicing and substring, which I do not want to use in this case.

I appreciate the help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`String.prototype.match`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match)

In case that the string does not have any number, which matches will return null, you should use [optional chaining `?.`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) for a safer array index access

```js
const str = "Channel.0.This.13";
const res = str.match(/\d+/g)?.[1];

console.log(res);
```

Comment: how do you make the Run code snippet window?

Comment: @eamanola you will see a small option in the editor here https://imgur.com/NuBVYNp

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
^[^\d]*\d+[^\d]+(\d+).*
```

Example:

```js
const secondDigit = "Channel.0.This.13".match(/^[^\d]*\d+[^\d]+(\d+).*/).pop();
 
console.log(Number(secondDigit)); // 13
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this regex `(\d*)$`. This will return only group with numbers which in the end of the string.

Comment: The issue with this is that I could also have a string like Channel.0.This.13.Another45. I specifically want the second digit not the last.

Answer (score 0):

You can reference the regex .match() key. `str.match(reg)[1]`

```js
const str1 = 'Channel.0.This.13'
const str2 = 'some.otherStrin8..'
const str3 = '65 people.For.&*=20.them,98'
const regex = /\d+/g

function matchSecond(str, reg) {
  str.match(reg)[1] ? output = str.match(reg)[1] : output = false
  return output;
}

console.log(matchSecond(str1,regex))
console.log(matchSecond(str2,regex))
console.log(matchSecond(str3,regex))
```

Answer (score 0):

`String.prototype.match()` returns an `array` whose contents depend on the presence or absence of the global (g) flag, or `null`

```js
const input1 = "Channel.0.This.13",
  input2 = "Channel.0.This",
  input3 = "Channel.This.";

const digitMatch = function (input) {
  const digits = input.match(/\d+/g);
  return (digits && digits[1]) || "Not Found";
};

console.log(digitMatch(input1));
console.log(digitMatch(input2));
console.log(digitMatch(input3));
```

if no matches are found.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the original string contains only alphabets, numbers and '.' (in between),

Here is my solution (Pseudo code):

```
String givenString;

regex=/([0-9]+)(\.[a-zA-Z]+)?(\.[0-9]+)/;

//below code will return an array or null (if no second number is present)

match=givenString.match(regex);

//access last element of array. It will be like '.13' , just remove '.' and you are good to go

match.pop()
```

Javascript Regex Docs:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions/Groups_and_Ranges

Answer (score 0):

It will help `.*?\d+.*?(\d+).*$`

```
"Channel.0.This.13.Channel.0.This.56".match(/.*?\d+.*?(\d+).*$/).pop()
// Output: 13
"Channel.0.This.13".match(/.*?\d+.*?(\d+).*$/).pop()
// Output: 13
```